# Floating text and icon over image

Tags: html, wordpress

I've seen on many websites where they have an image, then over that image they float some + symbol icons in various places. You can then click on these + symbol icons and they expand to display some text. I'm not sure what you would call this, so I don't even know what to Google to try and find something about how to do this. My Googling so far has turned up nothing. I'm using Wordpress and am wondering if anyone knows of a Wordpress plugin or a way to accomplish this, or at the very least what terms I could Google to try and find examples of how to create something like this.

Comment: You can search for 'Collapsible', 'image collapsible' or checkout this plugin http://dev.hey.uy/xpand-gallery-lite-demo/

Comment: I think you looking for hover effect or overlay effect. For example, see this link https://www.littlesnippets.net/